# Populating price data from Bloomberg in Excel with BDH via macro not returning time series

Tags: bloomberg, excel, vba

Though issue has been addressed before on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3auvhq/how_to_wait_for_bloomberg_data_to_update_before/), I was not able to find any useful answers.

I'm running a macro to populate price data with a macro via excel bloomberg API, say

```
=@BDH("AAPL US EQUITY"; "PX_LAST"; "ED-5AY"; BToday())
```

and

```
=@BDH("AAPL US EQUITY"; "PX_LAST"; "ED-3AY"; BToday())
```

My problem is that my macro is too fast and sometimes it does not return the proper time series. Sometimes it returns just one value in a cell or it will get stuck on `#N/A Requesting Data...`. I have been trying everything from trying to utilize `Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"` and `Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"` as well as all kinds of exotic waiting functions.

I could not figure out why this happens nor find a satisfying solution which would let me loop through all my securities and desired time frames. I found out that it seems to work better, if the function already knows the `cols` and `rows`, which can also be specified in `BDH`. But I am quite lost on this. So any advice on how to solve this annoying problem is much appreciated. You can use the macro I wrote.

```
Sub example()
    Dim startRange As Range
    Set startRange = Range("A1")
    
    startRange.Formula = "=@BDH(" & Chr(34) & "AAPL US EQUITY" & Chr(34) & _
        ", " & Chr(34) & "PX_LAST" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "ED-5AY" & _
        Chr(34) & ", BToday())"
        
    startRange.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=@BDH(" & Chr(34) & "AAPL US EQUITY" & Chr(34) & _
        ", " & Chr(34) & "PX_LAST" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "ED-5AY" & _
        Chr(34) & ", BToday())"
End Sub
```

I was able to replicate my problem, by running my macro in two different worksheets within the same workbook.

Comment: Best option is to request the data using the COM addin from VBA directly, you may find examples or libraries online. Alternatively you can try using `Application.onTime` to check at regular intervals if the data has been populated and continue your program once it's the case.

Comment: I saw the `Application.onTime` method in the reddit link. I literally copied the routine and call but it did bring any improvements. I will take a look at the COM addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better not to use (old) BDP/BDH, but to use either the COM wrapper (which can be synchronous) or the new BQL or BQL.query calls (HELP BQLX). Some time ago I wrote a a few lines of code (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661436/ ) to get synchronous behavior from BDP/BDH. In VBA, call Excel to search the range for value "#N/A Requesting Data". If something is still found, then refresh the calls, sleep 1/2 second and search again. else (if the search fails, then) all your data is ready.

Comment: I ended up using this approach http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2013/06/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-update-for.html

Comment: I used this one too, it works well.