# Best way to get Sharpe ratio and volatility based on BBG-data in Excel for automation

Tags: bloomberg, excel, vba

For tickerized portfolios in `PRTU`, I want to extract Sharpe ratios and historic volatilities per annum or for 1, 3, 5 years from Bloomberg. So far, I have been using [BBG V3COM API wrapper](https://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2013/08/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-update-2.html) to extract historical prices and performances for my portfolios. Now I want to add risk measures and implement these into my existing automated procedures.

What's the best approach to get the risk measures I mentioned above?

I was thinking to calculate them myself based on the time series of the prices (seems a lot of work) or maybe get them out of BBG directly? Ideally, I'd like to use the wrapper, as the built-in excel function `=BDH()` is impractical to incorporate into macros, as discussed in [one of my previous posts](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58646/populating-price-data-from-bloomberg-in-excel-with-bdh-via-macro-not-returning-t). Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in a comment in your previous post, BQL would be the way to go, and you should avoid using BDH.

Here is a simple examle of the inputs to get a rolling sharpe ratio for whatever tickers you want:

```
let(
 #dates=range(2021-01-04, 2021-01-15);
 #sharpe1y=rolling(sharpe_ratio(calc_interval=1Y), iterationdates=#dates);
 #sharpe3y=rolling(sharpe_ratio(calc_interval=3Y), iterationdates=#dates);
 #sharpe5y=rolling(sharpe_ratio(calc_interval=5Y), iterationdates=#dates);
)
get(#sharpe1y, #sharpe3y, #sharpe5y)
for("IBM US Equity")
```

In excel, just run `=BQL(x)` with x as a string with the above and you'd get something like this.

[image]

Shouldn't be too hard to add the standard deviation as well.

If python in an option, you could alternatively use Bloomberg's BQNT environment.

Comment: The problem is that `BQL` cannot see historical portfolio holdings, thus the returned values are incorrect, as I have rebalanced my portfolios in the past.